# How is multiplying A by A transpose related to the gradient in the least squares problem?

Tags: optimization, least-squares

I have a function:

$f(\textbf{x}) = \frac{1}{2} || \textbf{Ax - b} ||_2^2$

I am trying to minimize this function on values of x using gradient based optimization. The textbook I am following suggests the gradient can be computed as:

$\nabla_\textbf{x}f(\textbf{x}) = \textbf{A}^T(\textbf{Ax} - \textbf{b})$.

I am not understanding what has happened here. I am familiar with the notion of gradient, and how the function itself works, but I am not understanding why this computation represents the gradient.

Comment: Did you try finding an expression for $f (x)$ by using the definition of the norm and differentiating?

Answer (score 1):

In $$f(\textbf{x}) = \frac{1}{2} || \textbf{Ax - b} ||_2^2$$
you have a vector $\textbf v=\textbf{Ax} - \textbf{b}$. The absolute value is obtained either by dot product, or you can write it in vector form $\textbf v^T\textbf v$

Now the gradient is the same as taking a derivative with respect to $\textbf x$

$$\nabla_\textbf{x}f(\textbf{x}) = \frac{d\textbf v^T}{d\textbf x}\textbf v+ \textbf v^T\frac{d\textbf v}{d\textbf x} =\textbf{A}^T(\textbf{Ax} - \textbf{b})$$
In the last equation I've used the property of transpose of the product of a matrix with a vector.

Comment: Thanks, this was very insightful. I see how you decomposed $\textbf{v}^T\textbf{v}$ using the product rule. But how did you do the last manipulation? How is dvt/dx *v + vt * dv/dx = At(Ax - b) ? Please forgive my weak multivariable calculus.

Comment: Where do you have $\textbf x$? Just take the derivative. Then use $(\textbf{Ax})^T=\textbf x^T\textbf A^T$.